# DATE() type field shows as 0000-00-00 in JOIN query

Tags: mysql, date, join, null, format

When doing a JOIN query, MySQL outputs 0000-00-00 for a DATE() type field, despite values being not null when doing a simple SELECT (2017-03-02, etc.).

```
SELECT * FROM t1
JOIN t1_t2 ON t1_t2.t1_id = t1.t1_id
JOIN t2 ON t1_t2.t2_id = t2.t2_id
WHERE t1_id = 52
ORDER BY t2.type, t1.my_date_field;
```

Strangely enough, when I add a DATE_FORMAT(my_date_field) to the query it works:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(`my_date_field`, "%Y-%m-%d")
(...)
```

I did a SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23a965/8 but could not replicate the issue

**EDIT** The problem comes from the ORDER BY clause, removing 'ORDER BY release_date' "solves" the issue - still does not replicate on the fiddle though.

Comment: remove the ticks

Comment: I'd highly recommend creating a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com). It will help us diagnose your issue.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 there are no ticks in the version that does not work, how should it change the result anyway ?

Comment: SQL fiddle will help

Comment: @Ctznkane525 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23a965/8 see the edited post for additional info

Comment: You have no null dates...you have weird ones with 2014-00-00...is this what you mean

Comment: No, -ALL- dates appear as 0000-00-00 (null) when using the ORDER clause in the join query - But for some reason I cant reproduce the bug in the fiddle

Comment: Try to do an order by on the date format function as a whole...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164018/discussion-between-h-p-lafayette-and-ctznkane525).

Answer (score 0):

I have two options for you to try, considering your problem sounds like a mysql bug.

Option 1

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(alb.release_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
FROM artist art
JOIN track_artist_album taa  ON taa.artist_id = art.id
JOIN album alb ON alb.id = taa.album_id
JOIN track tra ON tra.id = taa.track_id
WHERE art.id = 1
ORDER BY tra.name, DATE_FORMAT(alb.release_date, "%Y-%m-%d");
```

Option 2:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT art.id as art_id, art.name as art_name, 
  alb.id as alb_id, alb.name as album_name, tra.id as tra_id, tra.name as tra_name, DATE_FORMAT(alb.release_date, "%Y-%m-%d") fmt_release_date
FROM artist art
JOIN track_artist_album taa  ON taa.artist_id = art.id
JOIN album alb ON alb.id = taa.album_id
JOIN track tra ON tra.id = taa.track_id
WHERE art.id = 1
) A
ORDER BY a.tra_name, a.fmt_release_date
```